# rake db:seed fails with error message Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a vary basic db/seeds.rb, one single line, fetching a sql file:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(IO.read("db/load.sql"))
```

And the content of the load.sql file is this:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO cities (id, name, created_at, updated_at) VALUES
(1, 'Goleta', now(), now()),
(2, 'Santa Barbara', now(), now()),
(3, 'Montecito', now(), now()),
(4, 'Summerland', now(), now()),
(5, 'Carpinteria', now(), now()),
(6, 'La Conchita', now(), now());
END;
```

When running the command

```
rake db:seed
```

I am getting this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO cities (id, name, created_at, updated_at) VALUES
(1, 'Goleta', now()' at line 3
```

I am able to execute without any error the same insert statement from the mysql console.
What I am doing wrong here?

Here is a new version for the file load.sql containing only 2 statements and failing after the first one with same error about the syntax as reported at the beginning of this post:

```
delete from stores_tacos;
INSERT INTO cities (id, name, created_at, updated_at) VALUES
(1, 'Goleta', now(), now()),
(2, 'Santa Barbara', now(), now()),
(3, 'Montecito', now(), now()),
(4, 'Summerland', now(), now()),
(5, 'Carpinteria', now(), now()),
(6, 'La Conchita', now(), now());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do this using a hash of values and a good-old ActiveRecord Class? The whole point of ActiveRecord is to protect you from SQL.

Comment: After 10 years with Oracle and 3 years with Postgres I don't need any protection from SQL. Just learning the differences with MySQL.

Comment: Okay. First, my apologies. I didn't mean 'protect you from' to be an insult on your SQL skills or experience. Honestly. I believe it is not an uncommon view that one of the benefits of AR is that, in creating an abstraction layer between Rails and the underlying dB, it can handle, on your behalf, some of the dB-specific idiosyncrasies. That's what I meant by 'protect you from'. So, again, sorry.

Comment: No worries, I am old backend guy moving slowly to the front end :) I edited the question to provide a load.sql file with only to statements a delete and an insert. The delete is fetched but I am getting the error when insert is reached. Maybe the ";" is not the right separator between the statements?

Comment: AR is amazing, I use it for one year with CYPHER dealing with Graph databases (Neo4j).

Comment: I'm relieved that I wasn't terminally offensive (I think). In any case, I've never done seeding of significantly-sized data sets. So, I fall back to AR usage (sometimes employing approaches to minimize AR overhead) and don't go the raw SQL route. As such, I fear I'll be of little use to you.

Comment: Problem is that file with multiple statements encapsulated between an BEGIN; and an END; worked in Postgres. I just inherited and attempted to use it for MySQL. Apparently is not possible. I always considered bulk inserts faster than individual inserts generated through AR from Ruby.

Comment: Have you looked at this? Probably not a silver bullet, but maybe helpful. https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/

Comment: Thanks but I am not looking for similar solutions I use in the past based on some Ruby methods. I was looking for a pure SQL solution using minimal Ruby. Something like this. One single line in Ruby loading a file: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(IO.read("db/load.sql")) and the load.sql file having all SQL statements necessary.

Comment: Looks that my problem is quire old and other peoples experienced the same. I did a GOOGLE search using this string "ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(IO.read(" and I got some interesting links. I will analyze them.

Comment: One of the solution there deals with separations of the statements in the same file, that thing I suspected to be the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `BEGIN` and `END` tokens.

This tokens are suposed to be inside a stored procedures triggers or events.

> BEGIN ... END syntax is used for writing compound statements, which
>   can appear within stored programs (stored procedures and functions,
>   triggers, and events). A compound statement can contain multiple
>   statements, enclosed by the BEGIN and END keywords. statement_list
>   represents a list of one or more statements, each terminated by a
>   semicolon (;) statement delimiter. The statement_list itself is
>   optional, so the empty compound statement (BEGIN END) is legal.

Source:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/begin-end.html

Comment: It worked. It is possible to have to statements in the same file? I added a delete from cities;  before the insert and delete is executed but insert fails with the same error.